# Eclipse Kepler Does Not Show Docs

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing a problem, as the title suggests, have no idea what happened here. My eclipse does not show comments/docs in bubble any more. As you can see I have written some comments on a method but still it would not show them.

Note: I have restarted eclipse + PC several times without any success. The comments do not even appear for my own methods.

Please help[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

IDE's can be very moody sometimes.  Try either completely restarting eclipse or restarting your machine all together.  If all else fails, reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse may not showing code docs in different situations -

- The code may have not java doc
- Or the jar file for the code is not added in eclipse classpath

Comment: Edited my question. The method is local, not from any jar.

Comment: @Fahad Ishaque In this case does the local method have the javadoc with the /** */ comment section?

Comment: You are working in abc() method. I think that's why you are not able to seeing the javadoc. When you use the method in other code then you can see the doc

Comment: Its not appearing in other classes when I call abc(); .